# Найти повторяющиеся элементы списка

Tags: python, список

Есть список `A`. Количество элементов порядка 2-8млн.

Проверяю его на наличие повторений следующим образом:

```
print len(listA)
print len(set(listA))
```

Результаты получаются различными, что указывает на наличие повторений.

Вопрос. Как получить список, состоящий только из повторяющихся элементов?

Comment: [1,1, 1,2, 2, 3] вы хотите получить [1,1, 2] или [1,2]?

Comment: @nick_gabpe не принципиально

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import collections
a=[1,2, 2, 3,3,3,4,4,4,4] 
print [item for item, count in collections.Counter(a).items() if count > 1] # [2,3,4]
```